# Undefined index: und on .tpl.php for content type

Tags: 7

How can i fix the error message?

> the error message is Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line
>   9 of /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/custom/theme/icons.tpl.php).

my code is:

```
<?php 
global $language ;  
global $base_url , $base_path ;
$lang = $language->language;
$count = 0;
foreach ($data as $kay => $node_obj) {
    $node = node_load($node_obj->nid);
if (isset($node->field_description[$lang])) {
    $img_url = $node->field_icon['und'][0]['uri'] ;
$count++;
```

?>

Comment: Depending on installed modules, and templates, the array keys can vary. Have you tried something like: ->field_icon[‘#items’][‘uri’][‘value’]?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by

add

```
!empty( )
```

like this

```
$img_url = !empty($node->field_icon['und'][0]['uri']) ;
```